# Konjunktiv I in "dann rissen wir uns darum, wer das Paket abholen dürfe"

Tags: grammar, subjunctive

Aus *Der Spiegel*:

> Dafür, dass unsere Wohnung im Osten lag, war erstaunlich viel Westen drin. In der Küche gab es einen Schrank, in dem Süßigkeiten aus den Westpaketen gebunkert wurden. Wenn ein Paketzettel kam, dann rissen wir uns darum, **wer das Paket abholen dürfe.**

Warum wird hier der Konjunktiv I **dürfe** benutzt? Schließlich ist es kein Zitat von jemandem und auch keine Anweisung.

Comment: Ohne mehr über die Grammatik dahinter zu wissen, empfinde ich es in erster Linie als Stilmittel. Es gibt dem ganzen einen (ironisch gemeinten) Hochdeutschen Touch. Als handele es sich um hohe Literatur. Dem ist aber nicht so, und das ist auch dem Autor klar, da er im Satz davor "gebunkert" und im ersten Satz "drin" verwendet. Besonders das passt registermässig nicht gut mit so einem hochgestochenen "dürfe". Deshalb empfinde ich das dürfe als Ironie (innerhalb des Schreibstils, nicht inhaltlich)

Comment: Ich empfinde die Verwendung des Konjunktivs an dieser Stelle als völlig normal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ein mit „ob“ oder einem Fragewort (hier: „wer“) eingeleiteter Nebensatz ist ein *indirekter Fragesatz*. Laut *Duden – Richtiges und gutes Deutsch* werden die indirekten Fragesätze zur indirekten Rede gerechnet.

Wenn der Inhalt der indirekten Rede als fraglich dargestellt werden soll, verwendet man den Konjunktiv:

> Er fragte, wer das Paket abholen dürfe.
>
> Sie überlegte, wer das Paket abholen dürfe.

Wenn der Inhalt der indirekten Rede nicht als fraglich dargestellt werden soll, verwendet man den Indikativ:

> Ich weiß, wer das Paket abholen darf.

Im vorliegenden Fall drückt der Autor aus, dass im Augenblick (wenn ein Paketzettel kam) noch unklar war, wer das Paket abholen dürfe:

> Wir fragten, wer das Paket abholen dürfe.
>
> Wir stritten darüber, wer das Paket abholen dürfe.
>
> Wir rissen uns darum, wer das Paket abholen dürfe.

Answer (score 4):

Die guten alten deutschen Begriffe helfen hier schon weiter: Indikativ = Wirklichkeitsform, Konjunktiv = Möglichkeitsform. Möglicherweise hole ich das Paket oder eben du. Da die Entscheidung noch nicht gefallen ist, gibt es keine Chance für den Indikativ.

Answer (score 2):

Wenn man "sich darum reißen" ersetzt durch "darüber diskutieren", wird es deutlicher: Der Inhalt des "Streits" wird wiedergegeben.

Ist an dieser Stelle aber schon eine reichlich ungewöhnliche Verwendung.